# Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, tomcat

Presento el siguiente error al momento de correr un proyecto:

Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error

Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje Error instanciando clase de servlet [controlador.controlador]

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instanciando clase de servlet [controlador.controlador]
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

causa raíz

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> controlador.controlador.(controlador.java:1)
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.

EL proyecto es creado en Netbeans 12.1, jdk 11 y Tomcat 9.0.38

Comment: Si adjuntases código, podríamos ayudarte mejor, porque las trazas te dan información pero sin el código es más complicado "adivinar" tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tengo netbeans 12.1 y tomcat 8.5.72, sufria del mismo problema pero lo resolvi agregado el siguiente plugin en netbeans: nb-javac library. solucion encontrada en: https://coderanch-com.translate.goog/t/738355/java/Servlet-giving-runtimeexception-Netbeans-IDE?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es-419&_x_tr_pto=nui,sc

Comment: Considera mejorar tu respuesta, considera incluir capturas si es necesario, ya que incluir enlaces externos puede no ser una respuesta concisa.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/299808)